# Pass copy of array via handler message with minimal allocations?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, optimization

I'm reading a Bluetooth data stream on a background thread and passing that data to the UiThread for processing and display via a [Message Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  A more detailed description of the process can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417945/java-threading-issue-with-handler-message-data-being-overwritten-by-next-message/6418056#6418056).

Currently I'm reading the InputStream to a `byte[]` and using [Handler.obtainMessage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#obtainMessage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) to get a message with the byte array as an object arguement.

I ran into a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417945/java-threading-issue-with-handler-message-data-being-overwritten-by-next-message/6418056#6418056) with packets overwriting each other because the array is not locked across threads and is being overwritten in the background before the UiThread can process it.  The obvious solution is to copy the array to a new array and pass that new object.

The problem is this is very expensive on Android and I am going to be getting a fairly continuous stream of data.  Is there a better way to pass this data to the main UiThread?
Perhaps by synchronizing the byte array or a more memory efficient way of copying the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to is pool of byte arrays that you can check out for use and check in when finished with. An implementation might look like

```
public class BytePool {
  private class PoolObject {
    public byte[] buffer = byte[1024];
    public boolean available = false;
  }

  ArrayList<PoolObject> pool = new ArrayList<PoolObject>();

  public synchronized byte[] checkOut() {
    boolean found = false;
    for (PoolObject obj : pool) {
      if (obj.available) {
        obj.available = false;
        return obj.buffer;
      }
    }
    PoolObject newObj = new PoolObject();
    pool.add(newObj);
    return newObj.buffer;
  }

  public synchronized void checkIn(byte[] finished) {
    for (PoolObject obj : pool) {
      if (obj.buffer == finished) {
        obj.available = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested or even compiled this code, its just meant to convey the basic idea.

With this you hopefully have the minimum number of byte[] objects allocated at any given time. Ideally you also want to add in some code to reduce the pool size if for some reason it expanded a bunch and now required pool size is smaller.

Personally I think you might be worrying a little too much about micro-optimizations before its clear whether you need it or not. (Or maybe you've already profiled your application and know that you need it.)

UPDATE: Hackbod's solution is actually more efficient than the one I suggested, although it still possibly suffers from having too many objects in the pool.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I used it as an example and it's working beautifully. On Android, reducing memory allocations is always a good thing, so avoiding 1024 bytes of memory allocation every time the bluetooth stream receives any data at all is a huge waste.  Also this was to fix a bug and the standard way to solve this bug is to just allocate a new array every time, so this is a better solution

Answer (score 5):

The typical way this is done in Android is to have a pool of allocated objects.  Make this class:

```
class DataBuffer {
    DataBuffer next;
    byte[] data;
}
```

And you can manage them like this:

```
final Object mLock = new Object();
DataBuffer mPool;

DataBuffer obtain() {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mPool != null) {
            DataBuffer res = mPool;
            mPool = res.next;
            return res;
        }
        return new DataBuffer();
    }
}

void recycle(DataBuffer buffer) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        buffer.next = mPool;
        mPool = buffer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How quickly is the data coming in vs. being consumed?

Why not allocate a 2nd array, one for reading one for writing, switching as needed.

When the stream is done writing to array 1, release its mutex and wait for array 2 to become available. Then you can pass array 1 via your handler to the UI Thread which will obtain a lock on that array. By switching the arrays like this you can ensure data is not lost because access to each is controlled via mutual exclusion.

A problem may arrise however if your data is coming in faster than it is being read. (Can the blue tooth data steam afford to block and wait?)

Comment: If I have a set of arrays that I can cycle through, could I reduce the blocking problem and still have a limited ammount of memory allocation?

Comment: Yes, all your allocation would be up front and constant through runtime. How many to allocation is up to you, you'll need to strike a balance between memory usage and speed. In general this approach is faster than dynamic allocation because there is no garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know android, but it's usual to read such data into a dynamically-allocated buffer, post its reference off in the message and immediately allocate a new one, ready for the next lot of data.  This eliminates the copying and ensures that the two threads are always operating on different data.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: The reason this is undesireable is because memory is a precious commodity on Android.  Continuous allocations of 1KB buffers would cause frequent Garbage collection which shows up as a noticeable UI latency on all but the fastest devices.

Comment: :((  other posters have already suggested a pooled solution, ie. allocating a P-C queue of buffer objects at startup. If you are producing data faster than you can consume it, you may be in trouble no matter what buffer policy you use.  Still, a pool will certainly help if your data is 'bursty', but you probably need plan 'B' in case the pool empties and your 'tooth thread blocks on the pool

Comment: The problem comes when a packet comes in and gets split up by the InputStream, not because it is coming in too fast.  I should be fine with a pooled solution.